# How do I add query parameter to Facebook og:url meta tag without impacting ranking of my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, query-string

I have a page which has open graph meta tags added to it. Now,I need to pass a query parameter to my page url, value of which will decide whether og:video meta tags has to be added to page or not. But as soon as Facebook crawler finds og:url, it ignores everything on the page and starts crawling canonical url given in og:url. If I add required query parameter to og:url, Facebook creates new indexing and my page ranking drops to 0.

**For example:**
**Current Behavior:**

*My page url:* http://www.example.com/mypage

with og:url value content="http://www.example.com/mypage"

**New Behaviour which I want:**

*My page url*: http://www.example.com/mypage?isValue=1

*Page will have this check*: 
if isValue=1 , it will ***Add video meta tags on page***

New page should have this og:url to propagate isValue=1 properly:

og:url content="http://www.example.com/mypage?isValue=1"

How can I avoid drop in my page ranking by new behaviour? 
Is there anyway I can make Facebook crawl og:url with query parameter added to it without affecting my page ranking?

Any other way of doing what I need to do, would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

That is the expected behavior. Facebook will always crawl the `og:url` aka the Canonical URL you are returning in your markup. Each URL is treated as a unique object, so if you are changing parameters, it will be a new object with 0 likes or shares.

It is also not considered good practice to have URL parameters as part of your canonical URL (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags)